# Dealing with xml in Scala play framework

Tags: java, xml, scala, model-view-controller, playframework

In **views** folder **kq.xml**:

```
@(code:String)
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">
        welcome
    </Say>
    <Pause  length="1"/>
    <Say loop="6" voice="alice" >
         your conformation code is
        <Pause  length="1"/>
            @code
    </Say>  
</Response>
```

In **controller**:

```
 def kqxml(code:String) = Action { implicit request =>
   try {
      Ok(views.xml.kq(code))
   } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        Ok(write(Map("result" -> "error")))
   }
}
```

But getting error:

```
 object kq is not a member of package views.xml
[error]           Ok(views.xml.kq(code))
                               ^
```

I also tried:

```
Ok(views.html.kq(code))
```

which of course didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do XML templates really exist? I always just used HTML.

But my guess is your template file needs to be called `xyz.scala.xml`, so: If you are in the root template directory `views` you should have a file called `kq.scala.xml`, and then you should be able to write `Ok(views.xml.kq(code))`.